# Get Image Size Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, image-size, imageurl

I am trying to get an image URL with attachment size using an advanced custom field. The field is set to ID. I've used this approach to get other images by ID with no problem. Yet this one isn't pulling the rendered image. It's pulling the ID number and displaying it on the page. I'm stumped...

```
<?php
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'listicles',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array (
        'taxonomy' => 'visibility',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'listicles-resortsvisible',
        ),
    ),
) ); 
    $listicleimage = the_field('listicle_featured_image', $post->ID);
    $listicleimgsize = 'listicle-thumb';
    $listicleimg_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($listicleimage, $listicleimgsize);
    $listicleimg_url = $listicleimg_array[0];
?>

<ul
class="row small-up-1 medium-up-2">

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>


<li class="small-12 medium-6 column">


<img
    src="<?php echo  $listicleimg_url; ?>"
    class="align-center" />

//THE REST OF MY CONTENT//

</li>
<?php endwhile;?>
<?php endif; ?>
</ul>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to change

```
the_field('listicle_featured_image', $post->ID);
```

to

```
get_field('listicle_featured_image', $post->ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `wp_get_attachment_image` and not `wp_get_attachment_image_src`.

`wp_get_attachment_image` accepts ID's as an argument.

Source: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/

Answer (score 0):

Add this to functions.php

```
function img_by_id($id, $size, $url) {
        $the_img = wp_get_attachment_image($id, $size);
        if ($url != true) {
            return $the_img;
        }
        else {
            $img_src = get_attr($the_img, 'src');
            return $img_src;
        }
    }

function get_attr($html, $attr) {
    $pc = explode($attr.'="', $html);
    $pc2 = explode('"', $pc[1]);
    return $pc2[0];
}
```

Then

```
<?php
    $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'listicles',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array (
            'taxonomy' => 'visibility',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'listicles-resortsvisible',
            ),
        ),
    ) ); 
    $listicleimage = the_field('listicle_featured_image', $post->ID);
    $listicleimg_url = img_by_id( $listicleimage, 'listicle-thumb', true);

?>
```

if you need full image attribute with sizes **$img = img_by_id( $listicleimage, 'listicle-thumb', false);**
If you need specific attribute from html tag **$attr = get_attr($html, $attr);**

I have this on my blank WP theme template.

Comment: Thanks for this. Its not working as of yet. The "src=" is blank, no image displaying in the img container.

Comment: Maybe we should move    `$listicleimage = the_field('listicle_featured_image', $post->ID);
    $listicleimg_url = img_by_id( $listicleimage, 'listicle-thumb', true);` inside while cycle

Comment: Moved it. Getting an offset error...Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /Users/robertrhu/Documents/Websites/vail/wp-content/themes/thisisepic/library/image-by-id.php on line 15

Comment: And what we have in line15? Can you paste whole code.

Comment: $pc2 = explode('"', $pc[1]);

Comment: Looks like we don't get image with` wp_get_attachment_image($id, $size);` **listicle_featured_image** is a are custom field right?

Comment: All the slugs are correct for both the custom field and the image size.

Comment: As always a mistake in syntax. Was using the_field instead of get_field. Ughhhhhh...thanks a million for your help! Loving this little trick for calling stuff.

Comment: inside while loop try echo image id `<?php echo get_field('listicle_featured_image', $post->ID); ?>` does all posts has images attached?